# Compress images to PNG in Mac Mail

Tags: mail.app

Is there a way to have Mac Mail compress images to PNG rather than JPEG by default?  I've noticed that a high resolution JPEG source image looks better when compressed to a low resolution PNG than a low resolution JPEG.

Screenshots can be saved as PNGs with this:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture type png
```

I'm looking for something analogous to this.

Comment: My mail just adds the image I present it, compression is optional. Just attach a PNG if you want a PNG

Comment: Thanks.  I know Mac Mail will keep a PNG a PNG, but I'm trying to save a step in converting a JPEG to a PNG.  I.e. my camera takes JPEGs, and I want to send out reduced resolution PNGs.  I'd rather not open the photo in Preview and reduce/convert manually.

Comment: It is not the task of Mail to handle this. Have you looked at Automator? Automator can convert, compress images and setup an email message (using Apple Mail)

Comment: That's helpful.  Thanks.  I will look at Automator.